# Dimension of a vectorspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V = \{f: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{R} | f(2) \neq 0 \}$ be a vector space. Find the dimension of V.

I believe that this vector space has infinite dimension and this is why:

We know that dim($P$) $<$ dim($V$) and that |basis($P$)| = dim($P$).

To find the dimension I considered $P \subseteq V$, where $P$ is the set of all polynomials such that $p(2) \neq 0$. Then we can demonstrate that this basis is not finite and thus V cannot have a finite dimension.

Assume that P has a finite basis, it will take the form $\{(x-a_1)^1,(x-a_2)^2,,...,(x-a_n)^n  \}$ where $a_i \neq2$. Now consider a polynomial of degree $n+1$. This polynomial is not in the span of the finite basis, so there cannot be a finite basis. Therefore, P has no finite basis. This implies that the dim|$P$| $=\infty \implies$ dim($V$) $=\infty$

I'm confidant that my proof is not the greatest, but does it make sense?

Comment: $V$ is not a vector space since it's not closed under addition.

Comment: @quasi Yes you are right. If we have $f_1 = a$ and $f_2 = -a$ then addition will fail. I cannot believe I didn't catch that. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the definition is not $f(2)=0$ ? With that definition, $V$ would be a vector space.